# Excel, merging similar data, but with some missing/added rows

Tags: excel

Having 2 following tables can I achieve the last table in an automatic way?

Input 1

| Service | Sep-21 |
| --- | --- |
| Service 1 | 100 |
| Service 3 | 300 |

Input 2

| Service | Aug-21 |
| --- | --- |
| Service 1 | 1000 |
| Service 2 | 2000 |

Desired Output

| Service | Sep-21 | Aug-21 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Service 1 | 100 | 1000 |
| Service 2 |  | 200 |
| Service 3 | 300 |  |

## Manual procedure

At the moment I sort services by name and then manually merged them by scanning for mismatches.

| Service | Sep-21 |  | Aug-21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Service 1 | 100 | Service 1 | 1000 |
| Service 3 | 300 | Service 2 | 200 |

becomes

| Service | Sep-21 |  | Aug-21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Service 1 | 100 | Service 1 | 1000 |
|  |  | Service 2 | 200 |
| Service 3 | 300 |  |  |

becomes

| Service | Sep-21 |  | Aug-21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Service 1 | 100 | Service 1 | 1000 |
| Service 2 |  | Service 2 | 200 |
| Service 3 | 300 |  |  |

and then I delete the extra column:

| Service | Sep-21 | Aug-21 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Service 1 | 100 | 1000 |
| Service 2 |  | 200 |
| Service 3 | 300 |  |

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multiple consolidation ranges to achieve the above result. To activate multiple consolidation ranges use (Alt + D + P) & add the data. Please make sure that the data range is Selected correctly.